# Define the sequences $x_n$& $y_n$ for $n \geq 1$ using the relations $x_n = x_{n+1} +2y_{n+1}$ & $y_n = y_{n-1} +x_{n-1}$ $?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Define the sequences $x_n$& $y_n$ for $n \geq 1$ using the relations $x_n = x_{n+1} +2y_{n+1}$  &  $y_n = y_{n-1} +x_{n-1}$ $?$

$:$

$n \geq 1$ ,  $x_0,y_0 \epsilon \mathbb{Z}_{+} $

$x_n = x_{n+1} +2y_{n+1}$

$y_n = y_{n-1} +x_{n-1}$

I came across this problem while solving some problems on limits of sequences,where in this question it asks to define the sequence. So, I tried out by finding the difference $d_x$ and $d_y$ as follows,

$d_x$=$x_{n+1}-x_n$= $-2y_{n+1}$

$d_y$ =$y_n- y_{n-1}$=$x_{n-1}$

then defining the sequence using the difference I got,

$x_n = x_0 -(n-1)2y_{n+1}$

$y_n = y_0 +(n-1)x_{n-1}$

But I know this is not the way because, after it asks to prove the limit.After quite researching I came to know about the recurrence relations, but I don't know anything about that.  I'm quite confused!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

We can arrange it as

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_n\\
y_n
\end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & -2\\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n-1}\\
y_{n-1}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

For $A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & -2\\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right]$ 
we have

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_n\\
y_n
\end{array}
\right] = A^n \left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_0\\
y_0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The recurrence behavior can be easily depicted by making

$$
A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -2 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
A^2 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
A^3 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
A^4 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
A^5 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -2 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

etc.

Note the periodicity.

Comment: Cesareo, I'm in my 10th grade & I didn't get it anyway.Isn't there some other way around!! If it's not then please explain it briefly.

Comment: @Invnto Apologize for the excessive formalism in the explanations. I hope it gets better understood now.

Comment: Yup thanks!! Cesareo